# How to split text by tags using PHP?

Tags: php, html, text, tags, split

I like to split a huge text by `<li></li>` tags after a specified amount of characters.

For Ex.

```
"biger text1 123 text biger 678 biger text"
```

to become

```
"<li>biger text1 123 text</li><li>biger 678 biger</li><li> text</li>".
```

Is it possible?

Answer (score 3):

In a one-liner, because everyone loves one-liners :)

```
$s = "biger text1 123 text biger 678 biger text";
$max_line_length = 10;

echo join("\n", array_map(function($item) {
  return '<li>' . $item . '</li>';
}, explode("\0", wordwrap($s, $max_line_length, "\0"))));
```

Returns:

```
<li>biger</li>
<li>text1 123</li>
<li>text biger</li>
<li>678 biger</li>
<li>text</li>
```

Comment: your one-liner is on 3 lines :)

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
<?php
$text = "biger text1 123 text biger 678 biger text";
$newtext = wordwrap($text, 10, "<li>");

echo $newtext;
?>
```